# Java - Why hash and key in HashMap are final

Tags: java, hashmap

In java, `HashMap` internally uses `Node<K,V>` that implements `Map.Entry<K,V>` and has the following structure:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final int hash;
        final K key;
        V value;
        Node<K,V> next;
```

I want to know why `hash` and `key` are `final` and `value` and `next` not?

Comment: In `Java 7` `HashMap` doesn't internally use any `Node<K,V>`, you are confused with something. May be you mean `Entry<K,V>`? But it has a slightly different structure.

Comment: @Andremoniy It does (in Java 8 at least): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Node

Comment: @assylias Oh, OK. It is `Java 8`. Previous versions don't

Answer (score 3):

**hash** - This is final as once node is created with an hash value it should not change even accidentally.

**key** - Just making hash as final doesn't make sense, as hash is based on key. So, both hash and key should be final for obvious reasons.

**value** - value in a node can always change, so no point making it final.

**next** - this is just a pointer and in a hashmap data structure next can point to different map entry, as it grows (insert/delete) or restructured (rehashing). So again no point making it final. But remember, the key a node/entry contains will never change.

Comment: If hash and key would have been non-final, in what way these will get modified? hashcode computes the same same hash code every time.

Comment: @GauravSeth Technically whatever you have defined in Node class as non-final, the value of the same can be changed in other classes. And you as a developer to safegaurd such mistakes to happen by someone else, you should declare it as final.

Answer (score 2):

The hash and the key define where this `Node` will be located within the HashMap's data structure, so it is important that these can't be changed once the `Node` is inserted, in order that the `Node` can be found again.

The actual value stored is irrelevant from the HashMap's point of view; I guess it might be a slight optimization not to need to create a new `Node` if you change the value associated with a key.

The next node can change if you add/remove elements from the map.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to deal with re-hashing. But, I am not very sure how.